# How to send the header to the client before execute the php scripts

Tags: php, header, buffer, ob-start

How to send the header to the client before execute the php scripts ?

My script take many time to finish and the client don't receive anything through this period.

```
<?

header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2011 10:16:31 GMT");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: 12275768");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Untitled-1.bmp"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Connection: close");

//Send headers now

//because my php script take many time to finish
//because it downloads a file from a remote server

.
.
.

?>
```

Comment: If you have the possibility, you should try to execute the time consuming script in CLI and manage its execution via a database table, that way you can leave the user free to browse the website while the script finnishes processing the info.

Comment: What exactly are you doing that takes this long?

Comment: @Gumbo : My script download a file from remote server and return the file to my client. I am using passthru("curl ...") to do that.

Comment: @faressoft: Ok, so you’re already passing the data through while receiving it. But did you also try a different way like `fopen` and `fpassthru` or a chunked response?

Comment: @Gumbo : I can't use fopen because I wan't to use cookies and ranges with curl.

Comment: @faressoft: You could use a stream context.

Comment: @Gumbo : http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php something like example 1 ? Does it help me more than passthru ?

Comment: @faressoft: You could try that with a [chunked encoding](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.6.1). I’ll try to mockup an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure how `passthru` works and if the command’s output is buffered somehow. But here’s another example using `fopen`, a streaming context for the request header fields and the [chunked transfer coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) with an explicit flush:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2011 10:16:31 GMT");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Untitled-1.bmp"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
header("Connection: close");

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r', false, $context);
while (($buffer = fread($fp, 512)) !== false) {
    echo sprintf("%X", strlen($buffer)), "\r\n", $buffer, "\r\n";
    flush();
}
echo "0\r\n\r\n";
flush();
```

Make sure *not* to use `ob_start` or any other output buffering.

Answer (score 0):

`ob_flush()` function flushes immediately output buffer. Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Yes, I put ob_flush() after the headers but nothing changed

Comment: and what must happend then? you may do? for example, echo ('<html><body> Please wait, your request is being processed');, and client will see it in its browser. what affect are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and output something, then [`ob_flush`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php); then output some more, then `ob_flush` again.

Comment: also try checking that in php.ini output_buffering = Off

Comment: Where should I put ob_start() and ob_flush ? After th headers ?

Answer (score 0):

In your php script create headers, start writing html code, then flush, and continue creating rest of the HTML.